# What's the limit for what's on or off topic with aquaponics?

Tags: discussion, scope

In regards to this question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/14497/2984

We have other questions about aquaponics, but it seems like there are two kinds of aquaponic systems. One that's meant to produce plants, and one that's meant to produce seafood.

- Since we're about gardening and landscaping, are we setting the bar at only aquaponic systems that are meant to produce plants?
- What about questions for the systems that are meant to produce plants, but the question is still about the fish inside of the system?
- Are questions about aquaponics limited to the plants?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would limit it to the aspect of growing plants hydroponically, since that's the focus of this site.

It shouldn't matter if the aquaponics system is intended as a source of plants, with water creatures as a side-effect, or if it's the other way around; so long as the question is about the plants in the system, it should be on-topic here.

I would say that cultivating the fish is squarely off-topic, since we only care about their poop when used as fertilizer for the plants. If we allow that, we'd also have to consider other animal husbandry topics such as raising chickens, cows, horses... to be on-topic too.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should only take aquaponics questions that:

- pertain to the growing of plants in these systems
- pertain to the conditions for these plants (which could possibly include animal related content)

and are not:

- about sourcing or finding these systems
- about the animals one can use in these systems, or the care of these animals
- about repairing/building these systems (this one's on the line, but doesn't seem like it is [covered in the help center](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

There will, of course, be possible edge cases, but we can take these as they come.

Also of note: [**Sustainable Living** beta](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) has more [questions tagged aquaponics](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquaponics) right now than [we do](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquaponic). Many of these questions will be on-topic there. There is also a possibility that some questions about the care of aquaponic animals will be covered in the scope of [**Pets** beta](https://pets.stackexchange.com/).